# How to make scrollbar overlapping page content

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I want to make scrollbar that overlaps the page. I wonder if there is a way to do it with pure CSS. I read an article about styling scrollbars with CSS (https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit) but I didn't get a result I wanted. I think it would be possible to do it with some JavaScript and HTML element with fixed position, but I prefer to do it with CSS.
[image: scrollbar]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have this same requirement in my project.

Here is the solution:

```
overflow: overlay
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Soo where did u put it? Which selector?

Comment: In the div which holds the content

Comment: Children nodes have their background clipped even with a transparent scrollbar-track

Comment: @Wahyu in scrollable parent selector.

Comment: doesnt help in 2019 - Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @knuhol Is you issue resolved? If yes, then please guide me.

Comment: @KunalTyagi unfortunately not, I needed to resolve it completely differently

Comment: This is no longer supported in any modern browser. This answer should get downwoted.

Answer (score 2):

As **Anugraha Acharya** said, the only CSS option is:

```
overflow: overlay;
```

But it is worth noting that this has been deprecated, so there is no telling how long it will work in Chromium / Webkit.

It is not supported in Firefox so, you will have to do the following to ensure Firefox can scroll too:

```
overflow: scroll;
overflow: overlay;
```

With this, Firefox will render like the "Normal" diagram in the original post and Chromium will render like "how I want scroll to look". Also, if Chromium ever drops it it will still be usable.

This currently works as of January 2022.

---

I believe, by deprecated, Mozilla means that it was never officially added rather than it was considered and has now been dropped. So, hopefully, it will be considered and made official. In the meantime, you take your own risk.

Comment: Firefox likes to call things "deprecated" when they mean "works everywhere but in Firefox".  Take MDN with a grain of salt for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow: overlay` constraint does not seem to work any more.

In 2024, you can check the [OverlayScrollbars](https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/) plugin, which might answer to this need.
There is also a related plugin, [SimpleBar](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/) which gives you minimalist scrollbars instead of bulky Chrome default bars.

For my part, the restrictions listed in these packages seemed a bit worrysome. I realize this is not a real answer to the question posted here, but in my case I just decided to follow a safer path and apply a minimalist style in css to scrollbars. The following works well as of today in Chrome:

```
/* Make scrollbar less intrusive in Chrome: */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f100;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #80808080;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can try changing the background of the Scrollbar to transparent-

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent}
```

Comment: It worked but i had to set the body width to the width of my monitor. By default body does not overlap with scrollbar.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: Works only for background, scrollbar cannot overlap content in webkit.

Comment: @mikl How do you solved this issue? Do you have a working solution?