# How to make a scrollbar that doesn't change the page width ? (like on mobile screens)

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to have a scrollbar that doesn't change the page width. On a desktop screen the scrollbar is next to the page content, but on a mobile screen it appears "on top" of the page content, with transparency (and is visible only when the user scrolls). Is there a way to have this mobile-style scrollbar on a desktop screen?

Most of the questions I found about this topic are at least 5 years old and do not do what I want, except somehow [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253887/how-to-make-scrollbar-overlapping-page-content), but it didn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548909/6745128 might be helpful

Comment: Thanks I will do it that way if can't find something closer to what I'd like

Answer (score 0):

mobile screens dont have a scroll bar the same way we do on pc.

but you can change the width and style the scroll bar like this:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 background: #333;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: linear-gradient(#a700ff, #00fff7);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#a700ff87, #00fff778);
 }


body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: No, this still takes space on screen. What I'm looking for is a way to force the scrollbar to appear the same way as on a mobile.